# What happened to the Chess Cafe website?

Tags: online

I have followed the Chess Cafe website for years, but it appears that the website hasn't updated since late May, and clicking on some of the links sometimes leads to a 404 error message. Does anyone know what happened to the Chess Cafe website?

Comment: I think there is an old post by someone about it recently. Maybe do a search?

Answer (score 2):

[Chesscafe announced](https://chesscafe.com/the-skittles-room/on-hiatus/) on June 2 that the number of subscribers was too low to sustain the site and that they would go on a three month hiatus.

Whether they will ever come out of it again is anybody's guess.

Answer (score 2):

I think Chesscafe has bitten the dust.  It's been over three months now and they are still "on hiatus."